# Splitting digits and latin letters from a string

Tags: php, arrays, split

Currently I have an array something like this

```
   [0] => IS-001 開花した才能「篠ノ之 箒」
```

From this, I would like to extract only the IS-001 part and leave the Japanese character behind to something like this

```
    [0] => 開花した才能「篠ノ之 箒」
```

Normal preg_split I am using currently only for white space but it seems like having some issue on the  箒」 character to fall into next array. So I decided if only I can split those non Japanese characters out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
echo preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+/u','','IS-001 開花した才能「篠ノ之 箒」');
```

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]` match a single character present in the list
- `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
- `u modifier` unicode: Pattern strings are treated as UTF-16.

Comment: yes this is working fine. Thanks. Possible if you can tell me what is that regex for?

Comment: @user1897151 do you have values after those japanese words too? If yes then you can simply remove that `^` from the pattern

Answer (score 4):

A solution to this is by using [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

So `$char = substr($str, $i, 1);` will become `$char = mb_substr($str, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');` and `strlen($str)` will become `mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8')`.

```
$str="IS-001 開花した才能「篠ノ之 箒」";
$japanese = preg_replace(array('/[^\p{Han}？]/u', '/(\s)+/'), array('', '$1'), $str);

echo $japanese;
```

(or)

Remove latin letters and digits from string

```
$res = preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/', '', $str);
echo $res;
```

Comment: seems like not working as it will replace my entire japanese language to full kanji. I do have hiragana and katakana words in it. Is it possible to remove only alphaberts, number and the - special character in this case?

Comment: @user1897151 The correct term is: «latin letter». An alphabet is a collection of characters, not the characters themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is the same in all your cases, you can use explode with limit parameter :

```
$string = 'IS-001 開花した才能「篠ノ之 箒」';
$array = explode(' ', $string, 2);

echo $array[1];
```

Comment: Oups limit should be set to 2, not 1 sorry !